# android expandablelistview can not use notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: android

i want to refresh my expandablelistview , but it seems there is no way to use notifyDataSetChanged()??

how can i refresh my expandablelistview?? thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your adapter extend BaseExpandableListAdapter or one of its subclasses.  This class has the notifyDataSetChanged method in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: ArrayList data = new ArrayList(); MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, data); ListView list = new ListView(this); list.setAdapter(adapter); ....../*notify if need*/ adapter.notifyDataSetChanget();

Comment: i wrote this to get Adapter :mp3_listView.getAdapter()              but only saw notify() and notifyAll()

Comment: try to do like this: MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(...); mp3_listView.setAdapter(adapter);.........adapter.notifyDataSetChanget();

Comment: or ((MyAdapter)mp3_listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();